# ng-xi18n Error: Unexpected value 'ServicesModule' imported by the module 'LoginModule'

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I have `LoginModule`

```
/* External Modules */
import { ServicesModule } from '@myservices/service';
import { ControlsModule } from '@mycontrols/controls';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    LOGIN_ROUTES,
    ServicesModule,
    ControlsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    LOGIN_PROVIDERS
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginComponent
  ]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

`ServicesModule` and `ControlsModule` are imported from another project (private npm repository).

AppModule looks as following:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    ServicesModule,
    ControlsModule,
    ROUTES,
    LoginModule,
    SomeAnoterLocalModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I see that I am importing `ServicesModule` and `ControlsModule` both in `LoginModule` and `AppModule`, but otherwise it is not working.

When I run the project, everything works fine, no problem. However, when I run ng-xi18n to extract translation texts, I am getting an error:

```
Error: Unexpected value 'ServicesModule' imported by the module 'LoginModule'
```

I have tried to remove `ServicesModule` and `ControlsModule` from the "child" module (LoginModule) and keep import in AppModule, in that case I am getting an error that tags (selector) from `ServicesModule` and `ControlsModule` are not recognized.

**Edit:**
The `ServiceModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [
    SERVICES_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class ServicesModule { }
```

It is only collection of services (providers).

Comment: How does the `ServiceModule` look like? Is the TS import correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the TypeScript import is not correct.

Comment: I have updated my post. Even I remove ServiceModule, I get error for ControlsModule. Import is done right as I am not getting any error during the deployment. Only ng-xi18n

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you mean in LoginModule or in ServiceModule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was not publishing `metadata.json` files. Using `ngc` instead of `tsc` solved the issue. Thanks to alxhub.